# CompletionException: NPE trying to read inputStream async

Tags: java, asynchronous, nullpointerexception, inputstream, completable-future

I am trying to read, in an async way, a file that i receive from the client. The idea is to recipt the file, validate it and if the validations are ok, send a response to the client saying that all it's ok, and process the file in background, so the user doesn't need to wait until the file is procesed.

For that I receive the file in my resource like an inputStrem:

```
@Override
@POST
@Path("/bulk")
@Consumes("text/csv")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response importEmployees(InputStream inputStream) {
    if(fileIsNotValid(inputStream)){
        throw exceptionFactoryBean.createBadRequestException("there was an error with the file");
    }
try {
        CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
    employeeService.importEmployees(inputStream);
        }).exceptionally(e -> {
            LOG.error(format(ERROR_IMPORTING_FILE, e.getMessage()));
            return null;
        });
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        LOG.error(format(ERROR_SENDING_EMAIL, e.getMessage()));
        throw exceptionFactoryBean.createServiceException("payment-method.export.installment-schema.error");
    }
    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

For the async part I used the runAsync() method of CompletableFuture.
However, inside of my employeeService.importEmployees() method I tried to read the inputStream and I am getting a java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.NullPointerException

```
public List<ImportResult> importEmployees(final InputStream inputStream) {    
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    try {
        while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) > -1) {
            baos.write(buffer, NumberUtils.INTEGER_ZERO, len);
        }
```

The inputStream is not null. And debuging in a low level, I can see that the wrapper of the class Http11InputBuffer is null when i try to read the inputStream.
Do you can see what errors i have or how i can set the wrapper attribute of the Http11InputBuffer previous to read the inputStream

Answer (score 1):

You are not waiting for the result. So it will return the `Response`before `importEmployees` is executed. You need to wait with a join/get before returning the response:

```
public Response importEmployees(InputStream inputStream) {
    ...
    CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> { ... }).get();
    ...
    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

There is probably no point in making this code reactive, though.